# Message Bridge - How to route messages from topic to queue - Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, jms

Is it possible to configure a message bridge for GlassFish? The message is currently posted to a topic, and customer requirement is to "redirect" this message from a topic to a queue. (both are on the same GlassFish server). By redirect, I mean, the message will be posted on the topic and then copied to the queue. I cannot find much documentation about this, I have read about Open MQ, JMS broker and JMS bridge, but this does not seem to fit this requirement.

I understand, that I can implement a topic subscriber and then post a message to queue. But I would like to know, if it is possible to do this just by configuration or do I have to implement a bridge?

Thanks for your help, I do appreciate it.

Vladi

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement a bridge... or change the submitter to submit to both the queue and the topic.

Comment: by implement, you mean to write an application, which listens on a topic and if an event occurs, it publishes it to the queue? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Yes, I meant write... just as you were stating in your question. "I understand, that I can implement a topic subscriber and then post a message to queue".